# no time display on grid view page

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am using SQL SERVER 2005, C# .NET.

I want to diplay date only on my grid view page, currently it showing including time also. 
I am restoring date in table with file upload button click function.
In my table i took Load date column data type is DateTime.
Exaple in table column showing like 10/19/2010 12:00:00 AM

On my grid view page also i am getting date column like 10/19/2010 12:00:00 AM

I want to show on my grid just like 10/19/2010.

```
string strDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LoadDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = strDate.ToString();
```

Below are the my code. Please any one can help me how to remove time on my grid view page.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            // Read the file and convert it to Byte Array
            string strClaimNumber = lblFileUploadCliamNumber.Text.ToUpper();
            string strDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

            string strDescription = txtDescription.Text.ToString();
            string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
            string contenttype = String.Empty;

            //Set the contenttype based on File Extension

            switch (ext)
            {
                case ".doc":
                    contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
                    break;
                case ".docx":
                    contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
                    break;
                case ".xls":
                    contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    break;
                case ".xlsx":
                    contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    break;
                case ".jpg":
                    contenttype = "image/jpg";
                    break;
                case ".png":
                    contenttype = "image/png";
                    break;
                case ".gif":
                    contenttype = "image/gif";
                    break;
                case ".pdf":
                    contenttype = "application/pdf";
                    break;

            }

            if (contenttype != String.Empty)
            {


                Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);


                //insert the file into database

                string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles(Name, ContentType, Data, Description, ClaimNumber, LoadDate)" +
                   " values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data, @Description, @ClaimNumber, @LoadDate)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value
                  = contenttype;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strDescription.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClaimNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = strClaimNumber.ToUpper();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LoadDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = strDate.ToString();
                InsertUpdateData(cmd);
                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

            else
            {

                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lblMessage.Text = "File format not recognised." +
                  " Upload Word/PDF/Excel formats";

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this inside of your gridview template:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDate" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", Eval("DateColumnName")) %>' runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are Selecting (retriving the Stored Date) the Date from the database table and displaying it in Datagridview Use the below mentioned Query,

```
Select Convert(Varchar(15),Datecolumn,1) from Tablename
```

the above Query will display the date in the 05/09/13 format.